# Check if the process is being run by SYSTEM user (from service)

Tags: python, windows, windows-services

In my application, I need to know if the currently running instance of my python desktop application was started by service (which shows under name 'SYSTEM' in task manager) or another user?

What function can I use to differentiate that ? I used `getpass.getuser()` but it returned my System name instead of 'SYSTEM'.

Comment: `GetUserName[Ex]W` doesn't return the user of the process access token, but rather that of the logon session that's associated with the process token (or thread token if impersonating). For SYSTEM this is the computer name because it uses the machine credentials for network logons. If you need to know whether the process token user is SYSTEM, just query it directly. With PyWin32 this looks like `htoken = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY);` `sid = GetTokenInformation(htoken, TokenUser)[0];` `system_sid = CreateWellKnownSid(WinLocalSystemSid);` `is_system = (sid == system_sid)`.

Comment: None of those functions/constants like TOKEN_QUERY are defined for me. What am I missing? @ErykSun

Comment: They're all in the win32security module, except for `win32api.GetCurrentProcess`. I assumed some familiarity with PyWin32 since you're probably using it to run as a service. FYI, PyWin32 installs a detailed doc named "PyWin32.chm" (compiled HTML) in the site-packages directory.

Comment: Tested. For somereason it always returns true if the service instance is running.  When it gets fired up from user instance,  I expected it to return False . @ErykSun

Comment: I'm not clear on the details here. If your service runs as SYSTEM, why would you ever expect the token user of the service process to not be SYSTEM?